# Function to produce an SQL query in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I would like to ask for your help.

I'm having trouble creating a function that would produce an SQL query statement using a list of columns.

Here are the details:
Example columns are: **ID**, **NAME**, and **ADDRESS**

The sample functions/methods are:

```
private void createQuery(String[] columns) {
   StringBuffer whereClause = new StringBuffer();
   for(int i = 0, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) {
      whereClause.append(columns[i]);
      doAppendAnd(whereClause);
   }
}

private void doAppendOrAnd(StringBuffer whereClause) {
   whereClause.append('AND');
}
```

However, the problem here is, I would not want the column ADDRESS to be included in the query. If ADDRESS is found in the last of the list, it would produce:
***"(ID = 1) AND (NAME = '123') AND"***, which would cause SQL error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual method is to write the separator before the term, and changing it from empty to something after the first one:

```
private void createQuery(String[] columns) {
   StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
   String sep="";
   for(int i = 0, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) {
      if (shouldselect(columns[i]){
        whereClause.append(sep);
        sep=" AND ";
        whereClause.append(columns[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

This will ensure you only write AND if you've written one term and are writing another. The `shouldSelect` method is of course yours to write depending on your criteria.

(Also use StringBuilder since you don't need the synchronization of StringBuffer).

Comment: Can I know the contents of shouldSelect() function?

Comment: I really like this approach, I had never thought to changing it after the first one, but instead doing a check first for the length. This is so much cleaner.

Comment: @VincentMercadoSy this is yours to implement, I don"t know your logic. Maybe check the name is not ADDRESS?